# How to open selected URL in app in Deep-linking or associate Domain iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I successfully setup the associate domain and deep-linking. Everything working fine but at one stage i encountered an issue that if user already has my application in his device and if he is trying to browse
my website on safari or any browser and tabbed on any link which contain my domain e.g www.eample.com it always opens my application

i don't want behaviour! i simply want that application should open on www.example.com/share? link only

[image]

i try it but... it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve  this  by  just  create subdomain  for sharing  purpose and instead on
applinks:www.example.come/share?

try  this

applinks:share.example.com/share?[image]

Comment: okay you mean i should  create a subdomain like share.abc.com

Comment: @aftabmuhammedkhan yes

Comment: Thanks  let me  try

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the paths inside the ***apple-app-site-association*** json file you upload in your server.

Only those path will be open your app and other will just open your browser.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "7H6EGD6TE5.com.test.app",
                "paths": [ "/share"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

There are different ways to specify paths, check out the ***Creating and Uploading the Association File*** section in below link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

This article will help to debug your associated domain registrations:

https://medium.com/@musmein/associated-domains-78843817f1eb